# Laravel Spatie/sitemap only contains 1 URL

Tags: laravel, sitemap, laravel-sitemap

I'm using spatie/sitemap

this is what i do to inform me that sitemap is created

```
Route::get('sitemap', function(){

SitemapGenerator::create('http://localhost/')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');

return "sitemap created"; });
```

and this is my APP_URL

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

i have 2 routes that could show up when i do sitemap:generate, but only this URL that contains in

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost/</loc>
    
    
        <lastmod>2019-03-07T11:54:02+00:00</lastmod>
    
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

is there anything wrong? i am using windows 10 for your information

Comment: You could try to have a virtual host and not run the app on `http://localhost`.

Comment: Is the route that is not showing up in the sitemap referenced anywhere in your view at `http://localhost/`?

Comment: @thefallen i try that using laravel valet, unfortunately its only for Mac. what should i do to try virtual host?

Comment: @DelenaMalan there is two route in my web.php and it is not showing up

Comment: If you have WAMP/XAMP you will have Apache or Nginx where you should add your application. Unfortunately I'm on linux and I can't point you to where the folder for this is, but you should definitely have existing examples that come installed as default,

Comment: @thefallen i'll try to do that, thank you

Comment: @DavaEranda your routes need to be referenced in your views and not just be present in your `routes/web.php` file. The package works by **crawling** your site. For example, your view at `http://localhost` should include a link to your second route, e.g. `<a href="/route2">Link</a>`.

Comment: @thefallen you're right, i try to do virtual host and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works when you're not using localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000. you should change your web address using laravel valet for MAC or change your hosts for Windows